# Deselecting Collection View Cell Not Changing Variable Value

Tags: swift, select, indexing, collectionview, deselect

I am trying to change my "selected" variable so that when a character cell in the collectionview is selected, the view controller can be dismissed when the user clicks the button (sendTapped). However, it is not changing the variable value back to false when the user deselects a cell, so the view controller is dismissed when the user deselects a cell and then clicks the button.

class CharactersViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {

```
let characters = [...]
let characterImages = [...]

var selectedIndex: Int?
var selected = false

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

@IBAction func sendTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    ***if selected {
            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            let initialViewController = UIStoryboard.initialViewController(for: .main)
            self.view.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
            self.view.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.characters.count
}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CharacterViewCell

    cell.characterImage.image = UIImage(named: characterImages[indexPath.row])

    if selectedIndex == indexPath.row {
        cell.contentView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.yellow.cgColor
        cell.contentView.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
    }else{
        cell.contentView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        cell.contentView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
    }

    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let character = characters[indexPath.row]
    ***selected = true
    selectedIndex = selectedIndex == indexPath.row ? nil : indexPath.row
    ProfileService.updateChild(child: "char", childVal: character)
    collectionView.reloadData()
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    ***selected = false
}
```

}

Comment: Are you expecting the user to deselect the same cell by clicking it again?
In CollectionView if Cell1 is selected and you click on Cell2 then didDeselectItemAt is called, But if Cell1 is selected and you click on Cell1 the didSelectItemAt is called again.

Comment: Oh. How do you make sure that the user has at least clicked a cell and it remains chosen before the user can click the button that dismisses the view controller?

Comment: Nevermind all I had to do was check whether my selectedIndex = selectedIndex == indexPath.row ? nil : indexPath.row in my didSelectItemAt was true